# Map.entry not working when hashmap is in function argument

Tags: java

I have following function.

```
public static void insertQuery(String tableName,HashMap ColumnValueArr) {

        if(tableName!="" && ColumnValueArr.size() > 0){                         

            Set set = ColumnValueArr.entrySet();
            Iterator i = set.iterator();
            while(i.hasNext()) {
                 Map.Entry me = (Map.Entry)i.next();
                 System.out.print(me.getKey() + ": ");
                 System.out.println(me.getValue());
            }           
        }
}
```

I  am getting error in following line.

```
Map.Entry me = (Map.Entry)i.next();
```

But as per my knowledge syntax is right.

so what can be the problem and what are the alternative solutions?

Thanks in advance for your precious time.

Comment: `tableName!=""` <-- NO. Don't use `==` to compare `String`s. What is more, `String` has `.isEmpty()`, use that. Also, why use raw collections in 2014? Why is your argument a `HashMap` instead of a `Map`?

Comment: Map.entry can not be resolved to type @Eran

Comment: Thanks @Eran. Your answer is right. My problem has been solved. how i can mark your answer is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix your `Map.Entry can not be resolved to type` error, you should `import java.util.Map`.